# practical git commands to compare/diff between various branches

Tags: git

I am still a bit weary of branches and comparing exactly what has changed.
I don't like how things are just dumped to the console, especially when file sizes are large and many files have changed.

If I plug in perforces diff, will I get this:

1. a list of branches, and changes
2. the ability to diff between branches and all affected files are easily comparable to other branches/versions?

Answer (score 3):

First, git by default uses pager when output is large enough, be it `git log` (or `git log --graph`) or `git diff`.

Second, you can use `git difftool` to run configured (or autodetected) graphical diff tool.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently use

```
git diff master...HEAD > branchdiff.diff
```

That compares the head of the current branch against the master, and dumps it in a file I can look over instead of dumping it to the console

Answer (score 1):

For a visual diff, you can use `git diff -p` along with `kompare`.

```
git diff -p <commit> | kompare -o -
```